# Searching in a list for a specified string

Tags: c#, string, list, search

I am trying to search a List of strings. I want to be able to return any found results that include information from a string. For example:

(I already have a list with values) List strings contains

> "dog", "cat", "doghouse", "doge", "mouse"

I want a way to check a string, for example:

```
string dog = "dog"
```

And return the values:

> "dog", "doghouse", "doge"

This is what I have so far, at least the portion I need help on.

```
Console.WriteLine("What would you like to search for (Title: Full Title; Author: first, last): ");
search = Console.ReadLine();

var results = bookList.Where(x => x.Contains(search)).ToList();
if (results != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(results);
    //i--;
    search = String.Empty;
    clearvars results;
    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue");
    Console.ReadLine();
    continue;
}
```

`search` is an empty string

`bookList` is my `List<string>`

`i` is just a counter, not really necessary for this

I am doing this whole thing in a `for` loop if that changes anything.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] containing the exact book titles you have registered as well as the exact string you're searching for. Right now we see neither so we have to guess as to why it doesn't work. For instance, are you aware that `string.Contains` is case sensitive, so if, for example, the book title you have in the list is "Doghouse", a search for "dog" (lower case `d`) won't match.

Comment: At the moment, the user inputs book titles. It doesn't really matter to me if it is case sensitive. Also, what you are searching for is also inputted by the user. Sorry...

Comment: You misunderstood me. I did not mean for you to change your program, I mean for you to create an example for this question that exhibits the same problem but is so complete that we can look at the code. For instance, if you later on say that "Oh, by the way, the user inputs the book title to be Doghouse, and then he searches for dog" then we're back to my comment above. Since we have no idea what the user does, can you please reproduce a specific case for us so that we can try to help you? Otherwise all we can do is guess.

Comment: Whoops, I'll get right on that, so, you basically want the else statement? Or do you want more of my code, or do you want all of my code?

Comment: I want you to prepropulate the list of things to search in with some strings (like the example strings you have), and to populate the string to search for with "dog", and then see what happens. Likely you will spot what the problem is by then. Also note that if you want case *insensitive* search you cannot just use `.Contains`.

Comment: @DatDudeAgain  I believe he's asking you for a brand new [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that we can copy, paste, and run to see your problem.  Preferably with hard-coded input instead of user provided input.

Comment: @inwenis answered the question perfectly. Sorry, for not getting back as quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate on every element of the result (the `results` variable).

```
Console.WriteLine("What would you like to search for (Title: Full Title; Author: first, last): ");
search = Console.ReadLine();
var results = bookList.Where(x => x.Contains(search)).ToList();
if (results != null)
{
    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

You need to iterate on `results` because it is a List. When you pass a list to `Console.WriteLine()` like this: `Console.WriteLine(results)` the method `ToString()` is called on `results`.
Calling `ToString()` on a List returns: `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]` which is what you have probably seen on you console.

`System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]` is a string representation of a list object, but what you're realy interested in are the elements of the list. This is why you need to iterete on the list and print each element separatly.

You could also join all elements of the `results` list into one string and then print it:

```
var allResultsInOneString = string.Join(", ", results);
Console.WriteLine(allResultsInOneString);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly. Also, thank you for explaining everything.

Answer (score 1):

You need a loop like [`foreach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) to iterate through the result:

```
foreach (var item in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Because as you said *I want to be able to return any found results* but since the `results` is a List of `strings` so you need to iterate through the list to print each item in the List.

Comment: What would item be in this case?

Comment: @DatDudeAgain  After you look at the [Documentation for foreach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx), you should be able to determine what `item` is

Comment: @S.Akbari -- Why are you so adamant that you "need" to iterate?  I've shown an example in my answer where you don't, i.e. using LINQ instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
string[] searchList = new[] { "dog", "cat", "doghouse", "doge", "mouse" };
string searchString = "dog";
var matches = searchList.Where((x) => Regex.IsMatch(x, searchString));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want use linq you can do this too:

```
  bookList.Where(x => x.Contains(search)).ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```